# Unable to keep Selenium Server Running after Putty Close

Tags: java, php, selenium

First, install the Selenium Server:

Download a distribution archive of Selenium Server.
Unzip the distribution archive and copy selenium-server-standalone-2.9.0.jar (check the version suffix) to /usr/local/bin, for instance.

Start the Selenium Server server by running java -jar /usr/local/bin/selenium-server-standalone-2.9.0.jar.

I can let it run but when i close my putty, the server shuts down. Is it suppose to be that way? As in, does the code initialize the server when they need? or how do I find a way to keep it running?.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal, when you close putty all your commands will be killed.
To keep your commands running, you need either to :

1. Create a script that will launch this command
2. run your command using : nohup java -jar /usr/local/bin/selenium-server-standalone-2.9.0.jar &